# How to make zabbix to send email every hour with item data

Tags: email, monitoring, zabbix

I want zabbix to send email with data, but not alerts based on triggers.

I just want to get an email like:

```
Host1
CPU: ...
Disk Space: ...

Host2:
...
```

with overall information I need.

Is there any way to configure that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While you could achieve that with escalations, it would be trigger based (even if it was a single fake item + trigger).

As you explicitly didn't want to do that, the next best solution that comes to mind would be scripting it with the [Zabbix API](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.2/manual/api).

Comment: Yes, indeed, using API is the best decision. I've already wrote some prototype which uses Zabbix API, thanks a lot!